# How to make a button show an alert box in my html document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, alert

I'm trying to make a button show an alert box. Basically you write something in an input form, then you click one button to show an alert box with what you wrote in it. You can see it here in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8jejp3a/2/).

My code looks like this:

### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="myblock">
            <div id="left"></div>
            <div id="center">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="a" value="Type your word here!">
                </form>
                <button><strong>Alert!</strong>

                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="right"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

### CSS:

```
.myblock {
    margin-top:60px;
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
}
#left {
    height:100px;
    width:33%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:green
}
#center {
    height:100px;
    width:33%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red
}
#right {
    height:100px;
    width:33%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:blue
}
form {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:50px;
}
button {
    height:35px;
    width:70px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

### JavaScript:

This is the part I think I am getting wrong

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var word = $("input[name=a]").val();
        alert(word);
    });
})
```

So why is it not working? I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: [You don't appear to be including the jQuery library](http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/x8jejp3a/3/) [(put it into your HTML)](http://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn)

Comment: what error it show in console? as @scrowler said, you might forget to include jquery library.

Comment: Ohh, yea I was not including the jQuery library in my HTML. Wow, it was so simple. Thanks for the replies people!

Comment: Yeah, there are multiple problems with your code, but here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/x8jejp3a/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have't **[include](http://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn)** Jquery library:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var word = $("input[name=a]").val();
        alert(word);
    });
}); //added
```

[<kbd>Updated DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/a4wwk89g/): demo has included jquery library

[image]

## [Debugging JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#debugging-javascript)

I believe you should use *Type your word here!* as [**placeholder**](http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)

```
<input type="text" name="a" value="" placeholder="Type your word here!">
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem, and your suggestion is more elegant indeed using a palceholder.

Comment: @wessy have a great jquerying. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use javascript?

Add `onclick="functionName()"` to the button and then

```
functionName() {
var word = document.getElementsByName('a').value;
alert(word);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/whrthw0j/) reference 
`for your better understandings`.

where I have given alert with the value present in the textbox.
and also I have used `placeholder` instead of typing string into textbox for default.

Answer (score 0):

You might have been forgotten one of those.

- Inlcude the jQuery library
- close the `$(document).ready()` properly.

Check again.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var word = $("input[name=a]").val();
        alert(word);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/L9j273n6/)**

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong here.

1. You have not loaded jQuery in your jsfiddle
2. You are missing a closing });

To load jquery in jsfiddle, there is a dropdown menu on the top left hand side of the screen that allows you to load libraries. Once you select jquery, you can click on Run button again.

But, you still need to fix your code ;)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var word = $("input[name=a]").val();
        alert(word);
    });
}); // You missed this here
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed closing simbols:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var word = $("input[name=a]").val();
        alert(word);
    });
**});**
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lwd5u4x/)

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your ready function, it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    var word = $("input[name=a]").val();
    alert(word);
  });
 }); // Add this line here
```

Besides in your jsfiddle include or enable JQuery because you are using one.